# SVG as background image not appearing

Tags: css, svg, background-image, scale

I've tried the usual solutions I'm finding on the net, but can't get the 
background image to appear.

In the first header, the SVG image seems to push out its container much farther than necessary for its `viewBox`. In the 2nd header, the background image doesn't appear at all. (SVG code is the same)

**HTML:**

```css
header {
  margin: 1rem auto 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container {
  border: 2px dotted orange;
}

.container svg {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#inline-svg {
  border: 2px dashed pink;
}

#header1 {}

#header2 {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' id='background-svg' width='400px' height='200px' viewBox='0 0 400px 200px'>
 <ellipse cx='200' cy='100' rx='200' ry='100' fill='green' /> </svg>");
 background-size: auto auto;
}

#background-svg {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<header id="header1" class="masthead">
  <div id="1st-container" class="container">
    <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' id='inline-svg' width='200px' height='100px' viewBox='0 0 200px 200px'>
      <ellipse cx='200' cy='100' rx='200' ry='100' fill='green' />
    </svg>
  </div>
</header>

<header id="header2" class="masthead">
  <div id="2nd-container" class="container">
    hello
  </div>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/c4fmou2n/

Comment: You can't have newlines in your data uri. The newline before the `<eclipse>` in your CSS is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add svg code in url please not break it otherwise it was not working.

```css
header {
  margin: 1rem auto 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.container {
  border: 2px dotted orange;
}
.container svg {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#inline-svg {
  border: 2px dashed pink;
}
#header1 {}
#header2 {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' id='background-svg' width='400px' height='200px' viewBox='0 0 400px 200px'><ellipse cx='200' cy='100' rx='200' ry='100' fill='green' /> </svg>");
  background-size: auto auto;
}
#background-svg {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<header id="header1" class="masthead">
  <div id="1st-container" class="container">
    <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' id='inline-svg' width='200px' height='100px' viewBox='0 0 200px 200px'>
      <ellipse cx='200' cy='100' rx='200' ry='100' fill='green' />
    </svg>
  </div>
</header>

<header id="header2" class="masthead">
  <div id="2nd-container" class="container">
    hello
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Sorry. That was something that happened in pasting for some reason. Doh.